# Где кроется причина ошибки Undefined variable: mas_cat_child?

Tags: php, парсер

Собственно, вот код, не могу понять почему выдается ошибка Undefined variable: mas_cat_child. Что делаю не так?

```
//парсинг с помощью phpQuery 
$pageText =new Curl();
$page=$pageText->get_page(URL);
$cat_page = phpQuery::newDocument($page);
$paginator = $cat_page->find('table:nth-child(2) > tr >td > a');
foreach ($paginator as $link){
$url=pq($link)->attr('href');
$url = "http://www.site.uz/rus/".$url;
$mas_cat_url[]=$url;

}
//print_r($mas_cat_url);


foreach($mas_cat_url as $child_link){
//echo $child_link;
$page_child=$pageText->get_page($child_link);
$cat_page_child = phpQuery::newDocument($page_child);
$line = $cat_page_child->find('table:nth-child(2) > tr');
foreach ($line as $l_link){
    //echo $l_link;
    $ln = pq($l_link)->html();
    $mas_cat_child[]=$ln;

}
 print_r($mas_cat_child);
```

}

Comment: Учусь делать парсинг и есть страница со ссылками, которые я заношу в массив $mas_cat_url. Вроде все хорошо, потом проходя по этим ссылкам открываю страницы и пытаюсь занести в другой массив и вывести на экран строки таблицы. Выдается ошибка о неопределенной переменной, не пойму почему.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, наверно, потому что вы пытаетесь манипулировать переменной до ее инициализации.

```
$mas_cat_child[]=$ln;
```

Здесь он пытается обратиться к переменной, как к массиву. А где объявление? Где указание, что это массив?

```
print_r($mas_cat_child);
```

Тем более распечатка. Если line пустой, $mas_cat_child не будет здесь задана.

Comment: Вы знаете, в первом массиве $mas_cat_url[]=$url; работает, вроде точно такое же выражение как и $mas_cat_child[]=$ln; Наверное все-таки line пустой.